# Intentando hacer un lector de texto

Tags: java, netbeans, archivo

Estoy intentando hacer un lector para hacer un generador de nombres aleatorios pero no entiendo porque al usar java.io.* y java.util.*, la File y FileReader no funciona (mensaje "Cannot find symbol").

```
package generador.model;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Modelo {
    private File f ;
    private FileReader fr;

    public Modelo() { }

    public String Leer(String archivo) {
        String valor_leido[] = {};
        f = "C:\\Users\\alexr\\OneDrive" + archivo;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el mensaje exacto, y en qué línea sale? En todo caso no puedes asignar un string a f (que es un File), tendrás que asignarle una instancia de File (hay un constructor que acepta un string).

Answer (score 0):

File F tiene que llevar un FileReader no un string, intenta con el siguiente codigo:

```
public class Modelo 
{
    private String ruta = "Disco:/Carpeta/OtraCarpeta/archivo.txt";//puse por ejemplo un .txt
    
    private FileReader file = null;
    private BufferedReader reader = null;
    
    public String leerArchivo() 
    {
        String linea;
        String valor_leido[]=null; // no olvides crearlo 
        try // no olvides tratar la excepción de lectura/escritura cuando lees usando BufferedReader o algún otro metodo:
        {   
            file = new FileReader(ruta);
            reader = new BufferedReader(file);
            while((linea = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
               //tu lógica de lectura al momento de leer
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) //la posible excepción mencionada 
        {
              System.out.println("No se puede leer o no existe el archivo indicado");
        }
        finally {
            if (file != null) file.close();
        } 
        return valor_leido;
    }
```